# I have added Support-v4, but cannot find ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, palette, support-v4

Today, I was going to make an ViewPager app by Android Studio. I have added support-v4 25.3.1, but I cannot find the ViewPager in the Palette. Can someone tell me how to find it?

Gradle

[image]

Palette Search Result

[image]

Comment: Try adding directly into xml? If you get the prompt in xml then it's not your gradle issue.

Comment: But how can I make it visible in palette? I have tried for many times to add it , but when I ran the app on the phone, something went wrong and I couldn't  fix it ahead of time.

Comment: Please check if there's any messages in Project Structure -> Problems and fix them if any, then re-import gradle project, check for Android SDK updates and finally you can try to downgrade api version used by Design builder (usually on the upper side of it).

Answer (score 0):

I think the ViewPager purposely not shown in the palette, I can't find it either on my Android Studio.
However, you can add it manually in the XML, for example:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

After that, try to ctrl/command + click on the ViewPager in XML. If it's opening the ViewPager java class, that means you already have added the support-v4 library(including ViewPager) on your project.